# How to get address of system call entry point?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

When a system call is invoked from 64-bit userspace to 64-bit kernel, syscall table is accessed from arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S, from the system_call assembly entry point. How can I get the virtual/physical address of this "system_call()" routine?

In other words, I want to know the address of entry point used by all system calls. I tried looking at kallsyms file but couldn't find it there. Perhaps, it has another name in kallsyms?

Reference: https://lwn.net/Articles/604287/

Answer (score 0):

What do you need this for? Are you sure you were inspecting kallsyms of the same kernel which was used in the article?

Figuring out what the func got renamed to is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's entry_SYSCALL_64 in my kallsyms file.